# HTML encoded string (using JSON) and jQuery Template

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a string returned from server with encoded HTML tags.

I use the following:

```
var result = $("#jobsTmpl").tmpl(results.data);
$("#jobsContainer").html(result);
```

In the template I am using the following for the string that contains the HTML encoded:
    {{html Body}}

I also tried ${Body} with no luck.

What's happening is that, the HTML string is displayed as encoded HTML, I just want to have the HTML take effect

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this out... http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/

basically where you want your string to be rendered as html and not encoded on the client you change

```
${NameOfProperty}
```

to

```
{{html NameOfProperty}}
```

If you are doing this and you are still getting encoded html, you need to change the server side code, as if your templates are as above then its not a problem on the client.

Sounds like your server side code is outputting your html tags encoded to *display* instead of *render*. In a Razor view you can use

```
@Html.Raw(Model.NameOfProperty)
```

in asp.net generally you can use

```
string unEncodedHtml = Server.HtmlDecode(htmlEncoded);
```

But really you should work out where / how its getting encoded in the first place, no point encoding then decoding.